# how to call methods created via prototypes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, prototypal-inheritance

i'm getting an  Uncaught TypeError: question1.pushIt is not a function

```
function Question(){
  this.question = [];
}

function Push(){
}

Push.prototype.pushIt = function(array,text){
  return array.push(text);
}

Push.prototype = Object.create(Question.prototype);

var question1 = new Question();
question1.pushIt(this.question,"is 1 = 1 ?");// error
```

Comment: ok. So what´s the question?

Comment: You are not creating any objects of type `Push`. Why would you expect `pushIt` to be available on objects of type `Question`? Is your intention that `Push` be a superclass of `Question`--in that case you have it backwards.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `prototype` and `Object.create` work here. `Push` is definitely not in the inheritance chain of `question1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/qmbag5f5/).

JavaScript:

```
function Push() {
    this.pushIt = function(array, text){
        return array.push(text);   
    }
};

function Question() {
    this.question = [];
}

Question.prototype = new Push();

var question1 = new Question();
question1.pushIt(question1.question,"is 1 = 1 ?");

console.log(question1.question); // ["is 1 = 1 ?"]
console.log(question1 instanceof Question); // true
console.log(question1 instanceof Push); // true
```